# Keras - Is there a Function to read out the prediction probability of face images and set a threshold for unknown faces

Tags: tensorflow, keras, face-recognition, image-recognition

The idea is to add a further class for unknown faces. It would be fine if there is a chance to set a threshold prediction to classify all faces to classes a-z and if they don't reach the threshold value classify it as unknown.

```
**Pseudo Code:**
if prediction_acc < 70%:
     prediction = unknown
```

Comment: In keras, `model.predict()` already giving the probabilities of each class.

Comment: I don't use model.predict(). Maybe there is a chance to set my idea in following code line: history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), epochs=10, batch_size=32, verbose = 1)